# Laravel 8. Смена role_id при регистрации для разных пользователей

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

У обычного пользователя role_id = 4, а у партнера role_id = 5

Подключён пакет `"laravel/ui": "^3.2"`

Когда создается пользователь то роль присваивается 2 по умолчанию где ее менять?

Comment: Зачем нам ваш require и что вы создали... Как регистрация проходит покажите. Обычно role_id это поле в БД либо с дефолтным значением, либо с триггером, который ставит role_id после выполнения запроса. И как вы понимаете обычный юзер регистрируется или партнёр?

Comment: вот именно я ничего не создавал выполнил команды и установилось форма регистрации автоматом, так вот мне нужно найти где меняется роль при регистрации,

Comment: это поле role_id bigint unsigned NULL не дефолтное

Comment: Ищите в коде role_id

Answer (score 0):

```
нашел нужно в
class User extends \TCG\Voyager\Models\User
{ 
    protected $fillable = [
        'role_id',//добавить
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];
}
и
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
   protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'role_id' => 4,//добавить строку с нужным id
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```